# React Native: Accessing values in returned object: undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a problem that I am apparently to stupid to solve..
I've been trying to solve this problem for to long, and it doesn't seem to crack.

I am fetching data from firebase using the following function:

```
export function fetchUserData(userID) {
   database.ref('users/' + userID).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot) {
         console.log('An error occured');
      } else {
         let user = {
            first_name: snapshot.val().first_name,
            last_name: snapshot.val().last_name,
         }
         console.log(user);
         return user
      }
   })
}
```

That function is returning an object, which I am trying to set in state when the component is mounting:

```
componentWillMount() {
   this.setState({
      userData: fetchUserData('10212667682706511')
   })
}
```

If I then try to log the `userData` to the console when the component is mounted, I get undefined, although logging the user from the `fetchUserData` function, I get the object:

[image]

I am assuming something is getting lost when I call `fetchUserData` and try to store it in state, but I simply don't know how to fix it, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your function `fetchUserData` **returns nothing**.

Your code `return user` returns `user` from the callback function (the parameter of `then()`).

One solution for this is to handle data within the callback function:

```
export function fetchUserData(userID) {
   database.ref('users/' + userID).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot) {
         console.log('An error occured');
      } else {
         // Handle snapshot data here
      }
   })
}
```

Comment: Ohh, I totally didn't realise that ! Thank you so, so much! .. I am however wondering if there are other ways of doing this, as I would really like the function: `fetchUserData` to return an object with the data from the snapshot?

Comment: @MichaelNissen You may find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function

Comment: Alternatively, if you return the promise from your function, you can chain additional `then` calls on the result to access the `user` value.